# Hidden textarea still shows at page load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working with AngularJS and I have a textarea that is part of a directive's template. I want it to be hidden, so I tried `ng-show="false"`, `style="visibility: hidden"` and `style="display: none"`.

The problem is that that textarea is still visible when the page loads, for like 2 seconds or so, but is really annoying.

I also tried `ng-cloak`, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: The textarea is still visible even with `<textarea style="display: none !important;" ...` ?

Comment: can you provide the full html page. As ng-show="false" is working fine

Comment: Have you tried an ```ng-if```?